# Unable to match a regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

Consider you have the following text:

```
yada yada 
yada yada 1
;


<Hello.There>yada:EGHKJHKG, Source:QWEKGHGHJGKGHJKGHJKVMVNMVMVMVMVMVMVMBTDFHG, </Hello.There>
yada2
yada3
```

I want to be able to take the information after `Source:` and before `,` only.

I've managed to do it with this [site](https://regex101.com/) , and matched the source value
My regex expression is:
`<Hello.There>.+Source:(.+?),\s*</Hello.There>`

My python code is:

`match = re.match(r'<Hello.There>.+Source:(.+?),\s*</Hello.There>`
I get None for match after this line, any ideas?
(I tried many more regex options without success)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.match` matches only at the beginning of the string. You need to use `re.search` if you want to match not only at the beginning.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('llo', 'hello')   # only match at the beginning
>>> re.search('llo', 'hello')  # match anywhere
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000029BA4A8>
```

See [**search() vs. match()** from the Python `re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).